Vue3 Plugin Not display CSS
I try to build a plugin but the plugin works the CSS style not applied.
Here is my ViewerPlugin.ts:
import { App } from "vue";
import MyPlugin from "./components/MyPlugin.vue";

// export default function createViewerPlugin(app: App): void {
//   app.component("MyPlugin", MyPlugin);
// }
const createViewerPlugin = {
  install(app: App) {
    // Register a global component
    app.component("MyPlugin", MyPlugin);
  },
};
export default createViewerPlugin;

and my vite.config.ts:
import { defineConfig } from "vite";
import vue from "@vitejs/plugin-vue";

export default defineConfig({
  plugins: [vue()],
  build: {
    lib: {
      entry: "./src/plugin/ViewerPlugin.ts",
      name: "CreatePlugin",
      fileName: (format) => `create-plugin.${format}.js`,
    },
    rollupOptions: {
      external: ["vue"],
      output: {
        globals: {
          vue: "Vue",
        },
      },
    },
  },
});

Also part of package.json:
    
    {
  "name": "testplugin",
  "version": "1.0.0",
  "private": true,
  "main": "./dist/create-plugin.umd.js",
  "module": "./dist/create-plugin.es.js",
  "exports": {
    ".": {
      "import": "./dist/create-plugin.es.js",
      "require": "./dist/create-plugin.umd.js"
    },
    "./style": "./dist/style.css"
  },
  "files": [
    "dist"
  ],
  "type": "module",


I put My css style in <style scoped></style> in each component.
The plugin created and style.css in the dist folder next to create-plugin.es.js, but lost all the style, when I render the component.
Can someone help to find ? thank you

you need external vue


export default defineConfig({
  build: {
    outDir: 'es',
    minify: false,
    rollupOptions: {
      external: ['vue', 'vue-demi', 'lodash-es', 'uuid', 'events', 'less'],
      output: [
        {
          format: 'es',
          entryFileNames: '[name].mjs',
          dir: 'dist/src',
          name: 'codee-core',
          preserveModules: true,
          preserveModulesRoot: './',
        },
      ],
    },
    lib: {
      entry: './src',
    },
  },
  plugins: [
    vue(),
    dts({
      entryRoot: './src',
      outputDir: ['dist/types'],
      tsConfigFilePath: '../../tsconfig.json',
    }),
    DefineOptions(),
  ],
});




Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers in the help center.
